# Spring Boot static files deployed via WAR with bad encoding

Tags: spring-mvc, reactjs, tomcat, spring-boot, jboss

I am working on a project with spring boot web to serve a rest API (and using react.js on frontend) where embedded tomcat and dev-tools is used in development phase but is deployed to a jboss server via war file.

To keep consistency between dev mode and deployment mode, I am copying my front-end files to the classpath directory classpath:/public. This way of working is being very productive and I liked it.

The problem that is happening is that these front-end files have special characters (Portuguese characters) and only when I serve my application via WAR in jboss these characters are being displayed with problems. When I serve with embedded tomcat everything works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you double check that you are using UTF-8 in all your jboss configuration files?

Comment: I just checked my jboss files and two files were lacking enconding... but I fixed it and tried but no success... :(

Comment: What kind of Servlet have you configured to serve your static HTML/CSS/JS assets from your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC defaults to ISO-8859-1, embedded Tomcat overrides it to UTF-8, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1182

I fixed it with property `spring.http.encoding.force=true`